# Full, semi and mixed analytic gradients: The OpenMDAO paper

Tags: openmdao

In [The OpenMDAO paper](http://openmdao.org/pubs/openmdao_overview_2019.pdf) there are descriptions of the 3 methods (full, semi and mixed analytic gradients).

I wanted to clarify something. It is stated that semi-analytic technique is more powerful than approximating the whole models’ gradients.

Let’s take a problem with a single group with 10 “only explicit components” and has no dependency or cyclic connections as in [Sellar Problem](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.2.0/basic_guide/sellar.html). ( I guess here explicit or implicit does not matter as the system will eventually see the components as implicit, but anyway)

My understanding from the paper is that approximating each component with FD is still more accurate than approximating the whole problem with FD as in `model.approx()`.

Assuming my understanding is correct, I am confused about promoting such a usage because of the disadvantages I see;

- Each component requires multiple calls for gradient approximation. This is definitely more computationally expensive than approximating the whole problem which would be called only as many as design variables (+1) for one sided FD approximation.
- Each component requires a tuning of FD steps and maybe normalization of input/output so it would require more work. Is this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a model with only ExplicitComponent instances, then the situation is a bit more subtle and becomes much hard to provide a rule of thumb for.

TL;DR: The reality is that when using numerical approximations for derivatives the "best" solution is highly model dependent. Broadly speaking, if there are any ImplicitComponents with true nonlinear solves, then you're better off using a semi-analytic method. If you have a purely feed-foward model of only explicit components (no-cheating though, wrapped engineering codes are often really implicit) with no OpenMDAO solvers being used to converge multidisciplinary coupling, then you **might** get a faster faster with monolithic FD (although a semi-analytic approach will still typically be more accurate here)

---

The computational trade-offs are much more clear when there are ImplicitComponent instances in your model. So let us consider that one first. To make things simple, let us consider a model with only a single ImplicitComponent instance which provides its own internal solve_nonlinear method. Here, you have two options:

1) traditional FD method, which would computed d_outputs/d_inputs by taking steps across the `solve_nonlinear` method. This would involve fully re-converging the model for each FD approximation (once for each input).

2) semi-analytic FD which computes partial_outputs/partial_inputs by taking steps across the `apply_nonlinear` method and then relying on OpenMDAO's analytic derivatives capabilities to compute the totals for you.

For option 1, there are several problems, such as solver convergence noise (dependent on solver tolerance), subtractive cancelation, and the computational cost of re-converging for each step. If you had a very expensive nonlinear solve (i.e. it was costly to call `solve_nonlinear`) then this approach can get very expensive, especially if you have many inputs. Also, you must be able to guarantee the the solver will converge for each step you take otherwise you won't get any derivatives. In practice, this guarantee is hard top make, so there are numerical stability issues as well.

For option 2, even if you have MANY more implicit variables to deal with, you are only calling `apply_nonlinear`, which is generally several orders of magnitude faster than a full nonlinear solve. It also won't suffer as many numerical issues. Its is much easier to ensure you get a valid residual evaluation than a fully converged nonlinear solve, so that stability issue is practically eliminated. In addition, you don't need to worry about noise introduced from loose solver tolerances. If you use FD, you still will suffer subtractive cancellation for tiny steps, but that is the only real weakness (and that can be removed by using CS).

It's true that for option 2, you may have many more FD steps to take, since you're now taking partial derivatives with respect to many additional variables. However, since `apply_nonlinear` is so much cheaper on balance this works out in your favor.

---

Now back to your original question regarding large models of all explicit components. Here you have a more complex set of trade offs. First lets assume that all your explicit components are simple analytic functions (i.e. none of them actually call some kind of nonlinear solver or external engineering code).

Here, you don't suffer the problem of numerical noise from solver tolerance. and if you have few design variables, it is likely that the fewest function calls will result if you do the [FD at the top of your model.](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.6.0/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/approximating_totals.html) That might give you the cheapest FD cost, but depend on the accuracy of the FD it might also result in more optimization iterations and higher overall compute cost.

But, monolithic FD also makes it difficult to select a good step size to take because different components will perform different computations and ideally would have different optimal step sizes. Since you can only select the step at the design variable itself, you're stuck with however that propagates through your model. So you may get less accurate total (or semi-total if you do this in the middle of a model) derivatives that require you to take more optimization iterations.

Now, if we loosen our assumptions about the nature of the explicit components a bit, and say there really is an engineering code with its own internal solver wrapped in the model somewhere... what you really have there is an implicit component that you didn't tell OpenMDAO about. So again, it would be better here to wrap it as an implicit component (exposing the residual calculation). In this case, you can't monolithically FD the model while still taking advantage of the semi-analytic method. So here, you would typically prefer to FD each component separately. In an 2014 paper titled ["Automatic Evaluation of Multidisciplinary Derivatives Using a Graph-Based Problem Formulation in OpenMDAO"](http://openmdao.org/pubs/Gray_Hearn_Moore_EtAl-_2014_-Multidisciplinary_Derivatives.pdf) we showed just this. Even if you use FD on the most expensive analysis (the FEA solver) with tons of inputs, the semi-analytic method is still much faster compared to a monolithic FD.

---

One other advantage of the semi-analytic method that I haven't touched yet is that it allows you to **mix** FD, CS, and analytic derivatives. You can start out full fd, move to CS for some of your more non-linear computations, then when your development slows down begin adding in analytic derivatives. Each time you upgrade your derivatives, you will see your performance increase.

So even if the semi-analytic method is slower in the beginning, it provides you a path to upgrading that a monolithic FD approach can never provide.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, i am reading it. some clarifications: 1) you say ; That might give you the cheapest FD cost, but which might result in the lowest optimization cost. shouldn't this be "That might give you the cheapest FD cost, but which might result in the highest optimization cost."